# How to save figure with a variable in the same in python plt.savefig() python matplotlib 2020

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have seen similar questions and answer but they are very old and do not work.

```
for i in range (0,7)

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(energia-ef,dos[a-3],linewidth=0.6, color='orange',label='Central')
    plt.plot(energia-ef,dos[a-2],linewidth=0.6, color ='orange')
    plt.plot(energia-ef,dos[a-1],linewidth=0.6, color ='red',label='Layer')
    plt.plot(energia-ef,dos[a],linewidth=0.6, color ='red')
    plt.plot((0, 0), (-15, 15), 'k-', linewidth=0.5)
    plt.ylabel("DOS (number of states/eV)")
    plt.legend()
    plt.savefig('/Users/andreaangeletti/Dropbox/data/anand/surface/scan/7/relaxed/dos/p/i.png')
```

where i should be equal the value of the for.

Actually I will first have to create the first set of images but then I would run again the code and rewrite over the old ones.

How it would be possible to use a string instead to specify the entire path name as savefig() argument, except for i variable part.

Comment: Are you trying to do overwirite image or make new one?

Comment: actually I will eventually do both, since I will have first to create the first set of images but then I would run again the code and rewrite over the old ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write it i different time you need to do;

```
plt.savefig('/Users/andreaangeletti/Dropbox/data/anand/surface/scan/7/relaxed/dos/p/'+str(i)+'.png',bbox_inches='tight')
```

then after for, close it.

```
plt.close()
```

Comment: Can I define the fixed part of the path as a string right? In order to use it various times inside the code?

Comment: @AndreaAngeletti yes, you can.

Comment: how should I do it? Could you add it to your answer please?